# DiagBox to insert value to rotate image MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, insert, textbox, rotation

Good night,

I need a big help from you.

I wanted the user to request a value for rotate an image. -20 wheel to the right, to the left wheel +20.
Each time that the user enter a value and clicked "OK", the image rotates.

I have this code, but it's not going on any value.

```
prompt = {'Insert value to rotate'};

dlg_title = 'Rotation';

num_lines = 1;

def = {'Positive + | Negative -'};

answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);

imagemRot = imrotate(handles.image, (variable), 'crop');

imshow(imagemRot, 'Parent', handles.axes2);
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: This is too complicated.
I just wanted to make an edit text where the user filled in with the value and ran the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is in `imrotate' line. Assuming answer contains a rotation angle,

```
imagemRot = imrotate(image, answer ,'bilinear','crop');
imshow(image)
```